# How do you Unlock General Grievous in Lego Star Wars III?

Tags: lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars

Without cheats, I mean. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to collect 20 Gold Bricks, which will unlock the **Invisible Hand Bridge** in the hub area. This area is accessible by an elevator in the hangar.

After you have completed the mission *Grievous Intrigue*, in this area you can find the character token for the General. Once you've found it, you can purchase him from the hub.

Comment: Is the mission "Grievous Intrigue" part of the story-line starting with "Duel of the Droids" at Ruusan Moon?